# Customize BigBlueButton for Moodle

Tags: moodle, bigbluebutton

I would like to know if you could customize this plugin as below: 
1. send and receive images through chat?
2. upload files by teachers then appears all files uploaded in bottom and thumbnail to the main screen

if possible to do theses things?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to confirm Bigbluebutton API provides these features, You can refer here. https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html